# Best practice for array as property in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a model class in Swift, whose primary purpose is to contain an array of custom objects, but also has other methods/properties etc.

```
public class Budget: NSObject, NSCoding {
  var lineItems : [LineItem] = []

  // Other methods

  // Other properties

}
```

As I understand it, it's best practice to not make the property publicly settable, but I want it to be testable, so lineItems needs to be publicly gettable.

Reading the docs, I *could* do this:

```
 private(set) public var lineItems : [LineItem] = []
```

But then I have to write a lot of boilerplate code to recreate array methods, such as insert, removeAtIndex etc.

What is best practice here? At the moment, I don't need to do anything else on insert/removal of items, but I guess I may need to do validation or similar in future, but even so it seems redundant to have to write code that just recreates Array methods.

Would it be better just to make lineItems publicly gettable and settable? Are their circumstances where this would or wouldn't make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift's `Array` is a (immutable) value type, which means that

```
var a = ["object"]
var b = [String]()
b.append("object")
b == a // true
```

From this point of view it does not make sense to allow modifying an array and not allow setting it - modifying is basically creating new array and assigning it to variable.

Comment: OK that's helped clarify a misconception of mine, thanks.

So if you need to modify a property or an object which is an array outside of the file for whatever reason, it should just be internally/publicly modifiable?

So, for example there's never a requirement for:
private var arr: [CustomObj] = []

func addToArr(obj: CustomObj) {
    arr.insert(obj, atIndex:0)
}

Comment: Point of my answer is that If you want an array to be publicly modifiable, than you should make variable public (not only getter). OFC, there are cases when you don't want to make it publicly modifiable  and implement custom adding / removing methods.